# Wordpress Paginate with additional Parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, isset, pagination

The code below works great for paginating my custom post search results:

```
if( isset($_GET['pagination']) && $_GET['pagination'] != 'false'){
    $arguments['posts_per_page']    = -1;
    $pagination = 'true';
} else {
    $arguments['posts_per_page']    = 9;
    $pagination = 'false';
    $arguments['order'] = 'ASC';
    $arguments['meta_key'] = 'code_auto';
    $arguments['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
}
```

However, if someone has filtered the results using this:

```
if( isset($_GET['sort_price'])){
    $sort_price = $_GET['sort_price'];
    if($sort_price == 'ASC'){
        $arguments['order'] = 'ASC';
        $arguments['meta_key'] = 'price-6';
        $arguments['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    } else {
        $sort_price = '';
        $arguments['order'] = 'DESC';
        $arguments['orderby'] = 'DATE';
    }
}
```

The results paginate but don't include the sort_price query. Can anyone give any rewrites to include both arguments as i have tried many times but cant quite get it. Thank you!